# How to match slashes globally in regex except if it is at the start of the string

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-negation

Hello stackoverflowers,

i couldn't figure the solution out by myself and couldn't find a related answer so i seek your help :)

I'm working in a VB.Net 4.x environment where i usualy have to join windows styled paths from various sources that are very unreliable in its format (leading slashes, ending slashes, sometimes double slashes inside) hence i can't use `Path.Join`

My next best guess is to regex replace any double occurance of a backward slash with a single one:
`\\+`

which is too naive, as it also converts a server adress which starts with a leading double backslash.

pseudocode

```
"\\server123\\a\\b\\\c\\".replace(/\\+/g, "\") -> "\server123\a\b\c"
```

thats a problem. i want to exclude any leading backslashes from matching. So i though i negative lookahead it:

regex

```
(?!^\\+)\\+
```

which would work in my example. But it does not what i want it to do. It matches the second backslash slash and replaces it.

What is wrong with my second regex? how do i negative lookahead something at the start.

Thanks for any explanation and solution

Comment: Have a look at [Path.GetFullPath Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=net-5.0). It might be able to fix some of your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```vb
Regex.Replace(text, "(?<!^\\*)\\+", "\")
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%5C%5C*%29%5C%5C%2B&i=%5C%5Cserver123%5C%5Ca%5C%5Cb%5C%5C%5Cc%5C%5C&r=%5C) and the [VB.NET online demo](https://ideone.com/U29HcT).

*Details*:

- `(?<!^\\*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there are any zero or more backslashes from the start of string
- `\\+` - one or more backslashes.